# how to use a progressing image on button click in user control pages

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

I have a page which consists of ajax tabbed panel. Each tab uses same user control page. In those pages on button click event, I am placing the progressing image untill the page loads. This functionality is working only in one tab, but it is not working in another tabs.

Help me out in finding solution.

```
`<script type="text/javascript">
function ButtonClicked() {
    //        document.getElementById("formsubmitbutton").style.display = "none"; // to undisplay
    document.getElementById("buttonreplacement").style.display = ""; // to display
    return true;

}
var FirstLoading = true;
function RestoreSubmitButton() {
    if (FirstLoading) {
        FirstLoading = false;
        return;
    }
    //document.getElementById("formsubmitbutton").style.display = ""; // to display
    document.getElementById("buttonreplacement").style.display = "none"; // to undisplay
}
// To disable restoring submit button, disable or delete next line.
document.onfocus = RestoreSubmitButton;
```

`

Comment: post some code..........

Comment: This is very generic question. We can't help you without some code. So put your code and then only we can help.